# Visual Studio shows errors in external files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

This is driving me nuts for some time now. I use Resharper a lot to dig into library code. The downside to this killer feature is that my Error List gets populated with errors in the source code from those libraries.

So if my own solution fails to compile, the Error List windows first shows a pleiade of errors from those external files, only to put the actual compilation errors at the bottom. It's *really* annoying, because after such a fail, I always have to scroll down through that window to search what's actually the cause.

Anyone has a clue at how to get rid of this "feature"? I'm not even sure whether it's VS or Re# throwing up at me. *Note: Solution-wide analysis is turned off.*

Comment: I have the exact same problem using VS Pro 2012, ReSharper 7.1.3. Press F12 (go to definition) on FtpWebRequest class for example, Re# downloads source to C:\RefSrc4.0\Source\.Net\4.0\...\fx\src\Net\System\Net\FtpWebRequest.cs\1305376\FtpWebRequest.cs. Then when compiling, VS shows loads of errors in the Error List for this file. I can still press F5 and run my web project, these errors don't stop running. Weird. Solution here (switch off external navigation) not good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539603/visual-studio-error-list-report-error-in-code-from-resharpers-decompiler-folder

Comment: I still have this problem too since several months. I just disable the decompile feature, see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539603/visual-studio-error-list-report-error-in-code-from-resharpers-decompiler-folder?noredirect=1#comment30263440_19539603)

Comment: But mum, I *want* to decompile :)

Answer (score 0):

To simply remove this error (and not completely deactivate the source decompile from Resharper), go to

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\SolutionCaches\[[Your Project Name]]\Decompiler
```

and delete any of the problematic folders. This will retain decompile features while removing the offending files.