# Visual studio Error List report error in code from Resharper's Decompiler folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.0

Everything is in the title, the versions of components in the tag.

The errors look like this :

```
Error   13522   Unexpected character '\u003A'   C:\test\myProject\_ReSharper.myProject\Decompiler\decompiler\04\fe6e72ab\Settings.cs    28  40
```

**More info**

Visual studio 2012

ReSharper version is : 7.0.1098.2760

Someone has a solution?

Comment: I am not the first one to have this problem (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728161/vs-tries-to-compile-resharpers-decompiled-code))

Comment: I have more than 10000 errors as this one : `\u003CModule\u003E.___CxxCallUnwindDtor((__FnPtr<void (void*)>) __methodptr(bway\u002ENET\u002ENativeString\u002E\u007Bdtor\u007D), (void*) &nativeString1);`, I don't think your answer is an option

Comment: Similar question here, maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248901/visual-studio-shows-errors-in-external-files

Comment: Yes! We start to become a community ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To simply remove this error (and not completely deactivate the source decompile from Resharper), go to

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\SolutionCaches\[[Your Project Name]]\Decompiler
```

and delete any of the problematic folders. This will retain decompile features while removing the offending files.

Comment: Thank you, But I am using version 7.0 and the path does not exist. And I guess the problem come back if you decompile again the file, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you decompile the same file again it would come back. That being said, most files don't cause an error, so I prefer not to disable decompiling.

Comment: In my case: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs12\v04\SolutionCaches . (You can use %appdata%)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do :
In Visual Studio => Resharper=> Option
Section Tools, external Sources select Default VS Navigation.

That's stop the decompilation, Then remove folder
_ReSharper.myProject\Decompiler\decompiler

Good luck!